# background color uneven in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am having a problem with the background color
here is my code for this frame

## First page to be displayed in the parent frame

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) #initializing parent class
        self.controller = controller

        #Labels to be displayed
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to the Grade Calculator", anchor="center", bg="lavender",
                         font = controller.title_font)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Please enter your name to start:",
                          font="times 30", bg="lavender")

        #entry 
        self.entry = Entry(self,bg = "yellow")
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Save and Continue",
                            command= lambda: self.cmmd(), height =3,
                             bg="green")

        #gridding
        label.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=10, sticky="EW")
        label1.grid(row=14, rowspan=3, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.entry.grid(row=14,rowspan=3,column=1, sticky="E")
        button1.grid(row = 19,column=1, sticky=W+E)


    #this function saves the typed name into student_name and displays the menupage frame
    def cmmd(self):
        self.controller.student_name = self.entry.get()
        print(self.controller.student_name)
        create(self.controller.student_name)
        self.controller.show_frame(MenuPage)
```

[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSJPo.png)
can someone help me with this?

full code [here](https://github.com/gurungnaresh495/gradecalc)

Comment: What is it supposed to look like? Is there too much white or not enough white?

Comment: i dint want any white. There are unnecessarily white in bg while i tried my best to cover it with lavender color

Comment: You gave al the widgets inside the Frame a background color, but not the Frame itself. Therefore all empty space inside the Frame is white. Give the Frame a background color with `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="lavende"')`

Comment: do you really need those hardcoded <cr> characters in the GradeCalculator.py code (line 116 and 118). There is no need to add a `.DS_Store` file in a repository. It is some kind of cache (for an image view application), it can and will be recreated often and has no purpose for other repository users. Add this file to your `.gitignore` file (after removing the tracking of it)

Comment: It was added unknowingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, I'm not the only one who failed that. ^^

You have to set the background of the Frame to `'lavende'` too, because its not completely filled with other widgets, so some of it is displayed normally. So just change:

`Frame.__init__(self, parent)`

to:

`Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='lavende')`

Comment: And also about the menu bar, do we need to do in every frame?

Comment: @NarEshGurØung What Menubar do you mean? I can't see one in the pic you shared. And no, if you fill the Frame completely you won't need to set its background color. For example if you want to resize an Entry and use a Frame for that you'll pack the Entry with `fill=BOTH` and `expand=True` so the whole Frame will be covered.

Comment: I mean to add a menu bar, do I need to add in every frame?

Comment: @NarEshGurØung Sorry I can't really follow you right now. Maybe I'm too tired (its 00:27 AM) or something. But if you mean a regular menubar then you don't need a frame. You add menus to the Tk/Toplevel by doing `root.config(menu=menuvar)` but not with a Frame.